# Playing video with AVPlayer like in FullScreen in Portrait

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, avplayer, screen-orientation

I want to play video with AVPlayer like in FullScreen like in Landscape device orientation but from Portrait orientation.

For that I need to rotate videoLayer. I tried to do that with code

```
 theLayer.transform = CATransform3DMakeRotation(CGFloat(M_PI_2), 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
```

but videoLayer does not start from 0;0 coordinates. It starts some where in the center.

Also, I set that

```
   videoPlayerSceneLayer?.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, bounds.size.height, bounds.size.width)
```

So, how can I solve that?

Comment: Did you find a solution ?